# Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found Error while Launching activity. kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

New android studio version android-studio-2021.1.1.11,  tried creating sample empty Android app, its showing this error.

I am trying this with KOTLIN

Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found

Error while Launching activity.

AndroidManifest.xml contains below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     package="com.example.myapplication">      <application         android:allowBackup="true"         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"         android:label="@string/app_name"         android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"         android:supportsRtl="true"         android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication" />  </manifest>
```

any solution to get out from that error, android app not opening due to that error.

I am a beginner. please give solution in detail

Comment: Have you added your activity in the Manifest file?

Answer (score 1):

```
**Check your manifest.. you are probabaly missing the intent filter that I have shown in snippet.**

 <activity
            android:label="main"
            android:name=".mainActivity" >
             <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I am totally new, I selected no activity at the start, so now I selected empty activity, now its working, and thank you so much for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare you activity in your manifest file.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="App Name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:theme,android:allowBackup,android:label"
        tools:targetApi="m">

        <activity android:name="com.app.ui.YourActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

  // Your other activities go here
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I am totally new, I selected no activity at the start, so now I selected empty activity, now its working, and thank you so much for the reply.

Comment: If it works and helped you then don't forget to Accept and up vote it ;)